# Factoring $9788111$ via Gaussian elimination over $\mathbb F_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields, factoring, cryptography, gaussian-elimination

I am trying to follow page 142 to page 144 of [An Introduction to Mathematical Cryptography](https://books.google.com/books?id=z2SBIhmqMBMC) by Hoffstein, Pipher & Silverman, where they give an example using Gaussian elimination over $\mathbb F_2$ as part of the process for factoring $N = 9788111$.

I am new to Gaussian Elimination done modulo $p$.

I am seeking the steps for how the results 1. and 2. below are obtained:

1. "the set of solutions turns out to be an $F_2$ vector space of dimension 8" on page 142.
2. Numbers in $v_1$ to $v_8$ on page 144.

I have attempted normal Gaussian elimination on the matrix on bottom of page 143, but cannot see how to obtain the above two results currently.

Comment: if you make up a smaller matrix (all entries $0$ or $1$), maybe 3 by 3, I can certainly show you how to row reduce it. I once wrote a computer program to do exactly that. If I am not back from the store, i imagine many people would be happy to typeset the process.

Comment: Ok how about for example $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1\\ 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix} . \begin{bmatrix}
u_1 \\ 
u_2 \\ 
u_3
\end{bmatrix}  =   \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 
0 \\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}$, mod 2

Comment: modulo $2$ is an especially trivial case as there is no subtraction and no division needed, just add the rows with pivots. So row 1 to row 2 in this example and row 1 to row 3 as well, etc.

Comment: Yes that makes sense thank you. Now how does the set of solutions get affected - ie question 1. above?

Answer (score 0):

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1&0 &1 \\
1 &1 &0 \\
 1& 1& 1\\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Got it, give me a minute; easy, as Henno says

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1&0 &1 \\
0 &1 &1 \\
 0&1 &0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1&0 &1 \\
 0&1 &1 \\
 0&0 &1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 & & \\
 & & \\
 & & \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 & & \\
 & & \\
 & & \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: Conclusion: only $u_1=u_2=u_3=0$ is a solution.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma yes. I think the OP ran away.

Comment: @willjagy thank you. No I haven't ran away - still periodically checking the page.